# Context not Permitted

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

This error says

> The name "deliveryDate" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

and the code is

```
snbYesorNo char(3) CHECK ((requestor = snb AND snbYesorNo = 'NO')
                          OR (requestor <> snb AND snbYesorNo = 'YES')),
delMonth char(3) DEFAULT DATENAME(month, deliveryDate).
```

And one last thing, what other command which I can use to make a if statement for ddl? I used `Check` and it seems not to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You want default value depending on other column. Use trigger or computed column

Comment: A default value can't include references to other columns? But why store delMonth as a separate column, you've already got that info in deliveryDate!

Comment: If you decide to computed column: `delMonth AS DATENAME(month, deliveryDate)`.

Comment: @lad2025 I did what you said I guess it is correct but it prompt `Column CHECK constraint for column 'snbYesorNo' references another column, table 'POGR'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1`

Comment: You cannot reference in check constraint different table. You need UDF for that.

Comment: @lad2025 So, instead of using `check` what should I use?

Comment: You need to define function which will check it]